# The only function-class automorphism of $(V, \in)$ is the identity

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

For my homework, I am tasked with proving that the only function-class automorphism of $(V, \in)$ is the identity.

I know Mostowski's Collapsing Theorem, which says that given a well-founded and extensional relation $r$ on a set $a$, can find a transitive set $b$ and a bijection $f: a \rightarrow b$ such that $(\forall x, y \in a)(x \ r \ y \Rightarrow f(x) \ r \ f(y))$ and $b$, $f$ are unique.

Define the sets $V_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha \in \text{class of ordinals}$  by $\in$ recursion with $V_{0} = \emptyset$, $V_{\alpha^{+}} = \mathbb{P}(V_{\alpha})$ and $V_{\lambda} = \cup_{\gamma < \lambda} V_{\lambda}$.

I know that $V = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{ON}}V_{\alpha}$. Applying Mostowski's Collapsing Theorem to each $V_{\alpha}$ (with the relation $\in$ which is well-found and extensional), have that the only bijections that preserve the $\in$ relation defined on $V_{\alpha}$ is the identity to itself (since $V_{\alpha}$ is transitive, and by uniqueness of Mostowski).

Suppose that there was a function class $F$ from $V$ to $V$ that was not the identity, so $F(x) \neq x$ for some $x$. Have $x \in V_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. Consider the restriction of $F$ to $V_{\alpha}$ called $F'$. The existence of this $F'$ contradicts Mostowski's Collapsing Theorem applied to $V_{\alpha}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why can't we argue by ∈
-induction directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have $x∈V_α$ for some $α$. Consider the restriction of $F$ to $V_α$ called $F′$. The existence of this $F′$ contradicts Mostowski's Collapsing Theorem applied to $V_α$.

Why is $F'$ an automorphism on $V_α$?

If $\operatorname{rank}(F(x))>α$ it is false.

After proving that $F'$ is an automorphism (that is: $F''V_\alpha= V_\alpha$), your proof will work.

Here is a similar method which is arguably simpler:

> Let $x$ be such that $F(x)≠x$ **and** $\operatorname{rank}(x)$ is the minimal rank with such $x$, and so $x\subseteq F(x)$, take $y∈F(x)\setminus x$ and look at $F^{-1}(y)$.

> This method shows that in fact Mostowski's Collapse Theorem holds not only to sets, but to set-like, well founded extensional classes in general (set-like is an order relation on a class, such that for every element, the class of smaller elements is a set)

Comment: Since $y \in F(x)$, then $F^{-1}(y) \in x$ which implies $\text{rank}F^{-1}(y) < \text{rank}(x)$ as $\text{rank}(x) = \sup \{\text{rank}(z)^{+}: z \in x\}$, contradicting minimality of rank of $x$. Is this correct? Why is $F(x) \backslash x$ non-empty?

Comment: @TomMisch first of all, $F(x)\setminus x$ is not empty because $x\subseteq F(x)$ and $x\ne F(x)$. $$$$ you need to explain why $F(y)\ne y$ for the contradiction, but note that it is simpler: if $F^{-1}(y)\in x$, then $y=F(F^{-1}(y))=F^{-1}(y)$ and so $y\notin F(x)\setminus x$